# Package taskscheduleR writecsv to directory location

Tags: r

I have an R script that I would like to schedule to run on a daily basis. The script queries a database and writes the results to a csv. Something like this:

```
library(odbc)
nzcon <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "NZSQL")
surveys <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = nzcon, 
  statement = 
    "
some sql here
"

dbDisconnect(nzcon)

write.csv(surveys,'surveys.csv')
```

If I execute the script within RStudio it writes the CSV to my working directory as I would expect. However, when I try to use the taskscheduleR addin my script runs but it writes my csv to C:\Windows\System32

How can I specify a location in which to write the csv? I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: can you write out the full file path like `write.csv(surveys,'z:/otherdrive/surveys.csv')` ?

Comment: Did you try adding a line to the script to `setwd`?

Comment: @Mike Thank you that was exactly what I needed.